# Salesforce Community knowledge articles - External Site

Tags: community, lightning-community, lightning-knowledge, website-integration

Anyone know if it's possible to surface a public/guest lightning community or just the knowledge articles on the community to an external site? If so, any pointers or guidance would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: By external site, do you mean a site that is not hosted on the Salesforce platform?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly .It's our corporate site, was wondering if there was a way to surface the community/elements of the community, say the articles, on to the site? Or how do companies traditionally use the community in relation to their existing sites - do they just link from their corporate to the community? Thanks :)

Comment: Linking is the easiest way to go and many do that. For non-Lightning sites/communities, iframe-ing the site isn't unheard of, ugly as it might be. On the other end of the spectrum, there's a [hybrid CMS option](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/introducing-salesforce-cms/). Warning: while hybrid CMS might look like the answer, this is a complicated option and still a developing product area.